# Why Is Method Spoofing not Working Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a form associated with the destroy method to delete a item/record.

```
<form action="{{ route('climb-excluded.destroy',$exclude->id) }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete
    </button>
</form>
```

**destroy() method**

```
<?php

public function destroy(Cexcluded $cexcluded)
{
    $cexcluded->tours()->detach();
    $cexcluded ->delete();
    Session::flash('success','Item sucessfully deleted !');
    return redirect()->route('climb.ie');
}
```

**Routes**

```
 Route::resource('climb-excluded','CexcludedsController', ['only'=>['store','destroy']]);
 Route::get('climbing/included-excluded','HomeController@getclimbIE')->name('climb.ie');
```

The trouble I'm having is the destroy method is not deleting the record from the DB and doesn't give any error. It is giving a session message without deleting the record.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your other thread with the same issue regarding the detach causing problems.

Add this to your Cexcluded model

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($model) {
        $model->tours()->detach();
    });
}
```

Remove the following line from your controller method

```
$cexcluded->tours()->detach();
```

So try this

```
public function destroy(Cexcluded $cexcluded)
{
    $cexcluded ->delete();
    Session::flash('success','Item sucessfully deleted !');
    return redirect()->route('climb.ie');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it didn't work as well. So I changed my destroy method to old conventional way.`public function destroy($id)
    {
        $cexcluded = Cexcluded::find($id);
        $cexcluded->tours()->detach();
        $cexcluded ->delete();
        Session::flash('success','Item sucessfully deleted !');
        return redirect()->route('climb.ie');
    }`

Comment: Really weird that detaching relationships is causing you issues. Anyway good that you got it work.

Answer (score 0):

You must use "->destroy()" in the controller.
Check this question for clarification between [destroy() and delete()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628981/what-is-the-difference-between-destroy-and-delete-methods-in-laravel)